# Flutter iOS app rejected because no purpose string for "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription", but the app doesn't use location services

Tags: ios, flutter, geolocation, app-store

I've just deployed a Flutter app to App Store Connect and received a rejection for the following reasons :

> **ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist** - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a *NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription* key
> with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely
> why your app needs the data...
>
> **ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist** - Your app's code
> references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's
> Info.plist file should contain a *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription*
> key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and
> completely why your app needs the data...

Now, I know how to fix this by putting that string into my Info.plist file, **EXCEPT** this app doesn't use location services.
(at least not as far as I am aware)

I want to tell App Store Connect that I do not need location services.

#### What can I check for in my Flutter code that might be making iOS think I want location access?

Comment: You are dealing with a robot here. It has scanned your app and determined that it references the location services api. This may be from some library your have included. If you can't find the reference then it may be simpler to put some value in for those strings.

Comment: That makes sense - I'm hoping for some method I can use to bulk search the app code myself for the reference.  I'm trying changing allowLocationSimulation="YES" flag to NO right now, if that does not work I will go with your suggestion to simply make up a reason.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, when you introduce the `SKAdNetworkIdentifier`, Apple will ask you yo provide these strings.

*But*!
To don't provide these strings *should not* be a reason for rejection if your app *actually* does not use user' location.

So either you(or a widget) actually uses the location, or your app was not rejected. Which you can extract from the fact that more likely in the first paragraph says:

> ...you **may** wish to correct the followin...